# How can I query from stored procedure using SqlKata?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, sqlkata

Here is my procedure in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [AUD].[Get] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT col1, col2 
    FROM AUD.MyTable
END
```

How can I return the result from this procedure using **SqlKata**? I can't find any helps in the docs

Comment: https://sqlkata.com/docs/execution/fetching-records#execute-raw-statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var users = db.Select("exec sp_get_users_by_date @date", new {date = DateTime.UtcNow});
```

This is from official documentation: https://sqlkata.com/docs/execution/fetching-records#execute-raw-statements

You probably want to call it like this:

```
var users = db.Select("exec [AUD].[Get]");
```